# CheckBox in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, mvvm

Hi I create this code for understand why if put a checkbox out to datagrid all work but if insert a checkbox into datagrid don't work.

This run correct:

```
      <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox" Content="Test" Margin="0" Command="{Binding SelectCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

But this not:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding XMLValue}" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox x:Name="TestCheckBox" Command="{Binding Path=SelectCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}}"  IsChecked="{Binding Path=Selected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

SelectCommand is only a  MessageBox.Show

(thank you and sorry for my english)

Comment: DataGrid does not have a SelectCommand property to bind to. Try with DataContext.SelectCommand

Answer (score 0):

```
 <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox x:Name="TestCheckBox" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}}"  IsChecked="{Binding Path=Selected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
```

i have tested your code ... you just have to modify your Path in your binding and use DataContext Property of your DataGrid ... not the DataGrid itself, the DataGrid Class doesn't have a property called 'SelectCommand':

```
Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping